Expand and linearly interpolate values for in between integers across groups using SQL
I have a table which has a value column, multiple columns on which to group and an "index" column which consists of integer values that are not contiguous. I want to expand the table by adding all missing intermediate indices for each group and linearly interpolate the value from the closest higher and lower value within each group
So given the below example:



index
group_col_1
group_col_2
value




1
A
A
1


3
A
A
5


5
A
A
11


2
B
C
0


4
B
C
8


7
B
C
2



I am looking to achieve the following



index
group_col_1
group_col_2
value




1
A
A
1


2
A
A
3


3
A
A
5


4
A
A
8


5
A
A
11


2
B
C
0


3
B
C
4


4
B
C
8


5
B
C
6


6
B
C
4


7
B
C
2




You have suitable (fully divisible) numbers in your example. What for (1,1)(3,2)? (1,1),(2,2),(3,2) or (1,1),(2,1),(3,2) ?  Show the interpolation formula.

for group_col_1 = B & group_col_2 = C, how do you determine that 1 row is needed between 0 and 8 (for new value 4), but that 2 rows are needed between 8 and 2 (for new values 6 & 4). Explain that logic please.

(For reference - this is written for SQL Server (T-SQL) - if you're using another type of SQL, you may need to adjust the syntax to fit.)
There are two key steps to solve this issue.

Determine the 'gaps' where rows need to be filled in (e.g., to make Index increment consistenly by 1)
For each row used to fill in these gaps, calculate the appropriate Value.

To do 2. above, it is a good idea (when doing 1.) to get all the relevant information on to the row, so the Value is simply calculated using a formula based on data on that row.
The key function used here is LEAD. It is used to find the 'next' value when the data is sorted appropriately. This means we can get data from other rows into the current row; having these, we can then perform the calculations we need.
To start with, for each row, we use LEAD to find the next values of

Index
Value

From the next value of the index, we can determine how many rows we need to fill by subtracting the current Index from the next Index and subtracting 1 (e.g., if the current Index is 3, and the next is 6, then we need to fill 6-3-1 = 2 rows).
For any given 'gap', we now know the number of rows to fill that gap, and the Values at the preceding and next rows - and by using LEAD we get this all onto one row.
These gaps can then be filled by copying the row as many times as needed, with Index values incremented appropriately. (The approach below uses a numbers table (Num) to help fill these gaps in with new rows - but note it will only fill gaps of up to 100. If you need more, then adjust the Num table.)
Having these, for each of the 'filled in' rows you can calculate the appropriate values by taking a simple linear fraction between the preceding Value and next Value e.g.,

if you need to fill 1 row, then the value for that row is the preceding Value + 1/2 the difference between the preceding and next Values.
if you need to fill 2 rows, then the values for those rows are the start Value + 1/3 and + 2/3 of the difference.

For the answer below, I've used the following table structure (to avoid reserved words like 'Index' and 'Value'). I've also reordered it so the grouping columns are at the front.
CREATE TABLE #Src (GrpCol1 varchar(1), GrpCol2 varchar(1), Ix int, Val int);

Below is the suggested approach. The answer (with some of the CTLs also separated) can be found at this db<>fiddle
WITH SrcWithLeads AS
    (SELECT GrpCol1, GrpCol2, Ix, Val, 
            LEAD(Val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY GrpCol1, GrpCol2 ORDER BY Ix) AS Next_Val,
            (LEAD(Ix, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY GrpCol1, GrpCol2 ORDER BY Ix) - Ix - 1) AS Ix_to_fill       
    FROM    #Src
    ),  

  Digits AS (SELECT N.n FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS N(n)),

  SrcWithFilledGaps AS
    (SELECT     SrcWithLeads.GrpCol1, SrcWithLeads.GrpCol2, SrcWithLeads.Ix, 
                SrcWithLeads.Val, SrcWithLeads.Next_Val, SrcWithLeads.Ix_to_fill, 
                Nums.n
        FROM    SrcWithLeads
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 + D1.n + D2.n*10 AS n FROM Digits AS D1 CROSS JOIN Digits AS D2) AS Nums
        WHERE   Nums.N <= SrcWithLeads.Ix_to_fill
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      GrpCol1, GrpCol2, Ix, Val, Next_Val, NULL AS Ix_to_fill, NULL AS n
        FROM    SrcWithLeads
    )

  SELECT GrpCol1, GrpCol2, 
         CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN Ix ELSE Ix + n END AS Ix,
         CAST(ROUND(CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN Val ELSE n * 1.0 / (Ix_to_fill + 1.0) * (Next_Val - Val) + Val END, 0) AS int) AS Val
  FROM SrcWithFilledGaps
  ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

Results
GrpCol1 GrpCol2 Ix    Val
A       A       1     1
A       A       2     3
A       A       3     5
A       A       4     8
A       A       5     11
B       C       2     0
B       C       3     4
B       C       4     8
B       C       5     6
B       C       6     4
B       C       7     2

Notes

I preferred a full set-based approach (i.e. do all the calculations for the whole set of data) rather than a recursive CTE or other loop, for efficiency - though it makes it a bit harder to understand
The Values for filled-in rows are rounded Integers, based on the position between the preceding and next value. An alternate approach may be to use the immediately preceding value (so if filling in 2 rows, the second row uses the first as its base) - but that's not used here.
As rounded integers, any filled in rows where the calculation results in .5 is rounded according to whatever rounding approach applies (up, down, bankers', etc)

